# How aircrack-ng captures packets? Is it use wire shark at back end?

Tags: packet-capture, packet-sniffers, sniffing, aircrack-ng

I am using aircrack-ng for packet capturing. I want to see the packet size and packet detail of every client aircrack-ng is sniffing. How it is possible using aircrack-ng? Is there any code inside airodump-ng which gives me that detail?

Comment: This is not a (as "one") question, but two.

Answer (score 1):

As for your title question

> "How aircrack-ng captures packets? Is it use wire shark at back end?"

`aircrack-ng` uses the `libpcap` library for packet capture and basic filtering, as does `wireshark` (via its `dumpcap` child process) and `tcpdump`.

You can see the numerous calls to pcap via the source code here:

http://trac.aircrack-ng.org/wiki/Sources

http://trac.aircrack-ng.org/browser#trunk/src

```
$ svn co http://svn.aircrack-ng.org/trunk aircrack-ng
$ cd aircrack-ng/
$ grep -nr pcap ./* | wc -l
398
```

398 references, all over the place.

```
$ grep -r --files-with-matches pcap ./* | grep "src/.*\.[ch]"
./src/besside-ng.c
./src/include/ethernet.h
./src/airdecloak-ng.h
./src/besside-ng-crawler.c
./src/packetforge-ng.c
./src/tkiptun-ng.c
./src/wpaclean.c
./src/pcap.h
./src/airdecap-ng.c
./src/airodump-ng.c
./src/airodump-ng.h
./src/airdecloak-ng.c
./src/aircrack-ptw-lib.c
./src/airtun-ng.c
./src/aircrack-ng.c
./src/wesside-ng.c
./src/makeivs-ng.c
./src/aireplay-ng.c
./src/osdep/file.c
./src/osdep/airpcap.h
./src/osdep/osdep.h
./src/osdep/airpcap.c
./src/osdep/cygwin.c
./src/osdep/linux.c
./src/airbase-ng.c
./src/ivstools.c
```

For more info on libpcap:

http://www.tcpdump.org/

Comment: these tools sniff packet data of devices which are connected with Ethernet. i want to sniff wifi devices. Actually i want to see what people are browsing in my range on their laptop or mobile devices using wifi.

Comment: @MunamTariq And why so many pcap code in a 100% wireless tool such as aircrack-ng? No, pcap is perfectly capable to sniff on wireless. Be it in normal or promiscuous mode (your wireless interface is seen as a wired interface, no difference) , or in monitor mode. See: http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap.3pcap.html and search for "wireless".

Comment: @MunamTariq Also see the numerous people doing wireless sniffing programing using pcap [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[pcap]%20wireless)